# How to pretty print email body in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to pretty print the output of email body here with some better format.

```
        - name: Email notification with better output format
          mail:
            host: localhost
            port: 25
            from: user@test.com
            to: user1@test.com
            subject: TEST
            body: 
                 Hostname: {{ value1 }}
                 IP: {{ value2 }}
          delegate_to: localhost
```

Just curious to know if there is some native way in ansible to pretty print email body content. Currently, I get the email body in the following format:

```
Hostname:test1
IP:0.3.100.1
```

I would like a better formatted email body output, something like:

```
    Hostname: test1
    IP      : 0.3.100.1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#format) and [indent](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#indent). For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ body|indent(width=6, first=true, blank=false) }}"
      vars:
        value1: test1
        value2: 0.3.100.1
        body: |
          {{ "Hostname: %s"|format(value1) }}
          {{ "IP      : %s"|format(value2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |2-
          Hostname: test1
          IP      : 0.3.100.1
```